# Integration of fraction

Tags: integration

Are there any special cases that make the following  true

$$\int\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} dx = \frac{\int f(x)\ dx}{\int g(x) \ dx}$$

Thanks

Comment: did $f(x)=g(x)$ is a special case?

Comment: At least, in some sense, you should have the measure of the set over which you integrate to be one, since if you average it out, in the second one they cancel.

Comment: Of cource, $f(x) = 0$ is a special case althoug rather trivial, where this is true.

Comment: Not anything which can be formulated in terms of mathematics is a good question in the sense that answering it will provide insights.

Comment: @Fabian what do you mean?

Comment: @Fabian I think this is a question worthi considering. Think about the product rule. The integral doesn't go directly to products but we have the product rule.

Comment: @Tyrone Now, now, according to the rules of this place, it's good practise to give background information and what you have tried about the problem.

Comment: @Fabian I agree but the way you are asking is implying that the question doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Tyrone: the first comment was rather general. If you read it carefully, you understand that the problem is exactly not that it does not make sense (your question makes perfectly sense). With the second, I did imply that I would be surprised if this question did come up in some application but again not that the question does not make any sense. By the way, I am not one of the downvoters.

Comment: @Fabian alright sure.

Comment: Without proper context and/or at least some self work shown, this looks like a whimsical question shot out of the blue. I can understand why people would want to know more about this question's background: at least, to get some insight from answering it or from dealing with it. BTW, $\;g(x)=f(x)\;$ doesn't make the cut.

Comment: Definite or indefinite integral? There is a fundamental ambiguity here because on the right, you have two integration constants, one in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $h=f/g$, the question is equivalent to
$$
\int h\int g=\int g\,h.
$$
If $a\,b=a+b$ then
$$
\int e^{ax}\,dx\int e^{bx}\,dx=\int e^{ax}e^{bx}\,dx
$$
for an for appropriate choice of the integration constants.